# Getting last updated time of module in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have written a simple Joomla! 3.x module to provide a notice to users for a site, but as part of the notice I want to display the "last Updated" details - so they can see when the information in the module was last updated. Is this information stored anywhere? or is there a way for me to automatically get/store this when the module is saved so I can retrieve it through the normal params?

I suppose worst-case scenario I could have JS run on click/change of the module config or save button to populate a hidden field with a timestamp - but that seems a bit hacky and I'd prefer not to do this if I don't have to :)

Thanks as always in advance :)

Comment: Where are you storing the information that is being updated?

Comment: I'm not doing anything fancy, just using the standard config.xml method because my config for this module is only really a couple of text fields (my first module so wanted to keep it simple); so it seems to go into the core Joomla! module tables.

Comment: Well you can add a calendar field that stores the current date (similar to the way the content components store modified date).  The you can render that.